# Array Index out of bound error

Tags: java, arrays

i am working on a program that reads input from file and give the output that how many strings are complementary.
here is the code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;




public class QuickSorting {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String data;
        Boolean status=false;
        int counter=0;
        int cases,case_item;
        String[]inputs;
        String to_cmp;
        String with_cmp;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File file = new File("input.txt");  
        //  Get data from this file using a file reader.   
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);  
        // To store the contents read via File Reader  
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        //writer to write in file

        data=br.readLine();
         cases=Integer.parseInt(data);
         //check total cases
        for(int i=1;i<=cases;i++)
        {
            data=br.readLine();
            case_item=Integer.parseInt(data.trim());
            inputs=new String[case_item];
            //check entries in each case
            for(int c_i=0;c_i<case_item;c_i++)
            {
                data=br.readLine();
                inputs[c_i]=data;

            }

            for(int i1=0;i1<(inputs.length-1);i1++)
            {

                for(int j=0;j<(inputs.length-1);i1++)
                { 
                    if(i1!=j)
                    {  to_cmp=inputs[i1].toString();
                        with_cmp=inputs[j];
                        status=compare_entry(to_cmp,with_cmp);
                        if (status)
                        {counter++;}
                    }
                }

            }
            System.out.println("The number of complementary strings  are "+counter);
        }

} 

public static boolean compare_entry(String to_cmp,String with_cmp)
{Boolean stat=false;
for(int i=0;i<(to_cmp.length()-2);i++)
{
    if(to_cmp.charAt(i)!=with_cmp.charAt(i))
    {stat=true;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
    return stat;}
}
```

But i am getting Array out of bond errorin line 58 that is in this line
**to_cmp=inputs[i1].toString()**;

Comment: shouldn't that for loop be: `for(int j=0;j<(inputs.length-1); --> j++ <-- )`

Comment: somebody just copy/pasted some code without reviewing it before compiling it

Comment: luiggi Mendoza dont be unfair. i have write that code myself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in for loop with j you are incrementing i1 again.
You have

```
for(int j=0;j<(inputs.length-1);i1++)
```

which should be

```
for(int j=0;j<(inputs.length-1);j++)
```

Comment: thanks i just write in a hurry and couldn't see that

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line:

```
for(int j=0;j<(inputs.length-1);i1++)
```

Fix it like this:

```
for(int j=0;j<(inputs.length-1);j++) // it's j++, not i1++
```

You see, you were incrementing the wrong counter. Also, the loop condition it's a bit peculiar, normally we use `i < inputs.length` : notice that we don't subtract `1` from the length, otherwise the last element in the array won't be visited.